# Java - creating an oracle date field

Tags: java, oracle, datetime

I have an Oracle `Date` type to which I need to insert the current date.

I am using Java to generate this date but everything I've tried so far yeilds the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Can anyone suggest java code to generate a proper date?

**Update:**

The dates in the DB look like `11-DEC-06`

SO, I've tried the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yy");
String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

And this doesn't work

Comment: *What* have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest instead of building a string query (which I am guessing you are doing), you instead use a PreparedStatement, which is generally easier (especially with things like this) as well as safer:

```
String rowToUpdate = "foo";
PreparedStatement ps = myConnection.prepareStatement(
      "UPDATE my_table SET date_field=? WHERE id=?");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);
ps.setString(2, rowToUpdate);
int updated = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Wow thats pretty much the exact code I ended up using..I figured it out a second before you posted...so I'll accept your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp, depending on your requirements.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Comment: yea I just figured the problem out. You are right, I was using a PreparedStament but setting the wildcard using setString instead of setDate...and I ended up using java.sql.Date..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make the query using a String version of the date then you may need to add the Oracle to_date function. You could do it like this (notice the extra d in the SimpleDateFormat)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Then in the query you would put

```
String query = "select * from table where date_column=to_date('" + date +"','dd-Mon-yy')";
```